# Convert RXJava Single to a coroutine's Deferred?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I have a Single from RxJava and want to continue working with a Deferred from Kotlin Coroutines. How to accomplish that?

```
fun convert(data: rx.Single<String>): kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred<String> = ...
```

I would be interested in some library (if there is any?) as well as in doing this on my own...
So far I did this hand-made implementation on my own:

```
private fun waitForRxJavaResult(resultSingle: Single<String>): String? {
    var resultReceived = false
    var result: String? = null

    resultSingle.subscribe({
        result = it
        resultReceived = true
    }, {
        resultReceived = true
        if (!(it is NoSuchElementException))
            it.printStackTrace()
    })
    while (!resultReceived)
        Thread.sleep(20)

    return result
}
```

Comment: You might find it easier to convert a function that returns `Single` to a `suspend fun` using `Single.await()` extension.

Comment: I have no Single.await() available with RxJava version 1...

Comment: You can use `awaitSingle()` that is available for any `Publisher` implementation (including Rx1).

Comment: Does not really work out with my Single. Code is here https://github.com/micgn/imagecatalog/blob/master/src/main/java/de/mg/imgcat/worker/LocationService.kt

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is this library that integrates RxJava with Coroutines: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/reactive/kotlinx-coroutines-rx2

There's no function in that library to directly convert a single to a `Deferred` though. The reason for this is probably that an RxJava `Single` is not bound to a coroutine scope. If you want to convert it to a `Deferred` you would therefore need to provide it a `CoroutineScope`.

You could probably implement it like this:

```
fun <T> Single<T>.toDeferred(scope: CoroutineScope) = scope.async { await() }
```

The `Single.await` function (used in the `async`-block) is from the kotlinx-coroutines-rx2 library.

You can call the function like this:

```
coroutineScope {
    val mySingle = getSingle()
    val deferred = mySingle.toDeferred(this)
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks. Unfortunately this only does the integration regarding RxJava2 and I have version 1...

Answer (score 3):

This converts a RxJava2 Single to a suspend fun with cancellation.

```
suspend fun <T> Single<T>.await(): T {
    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        val disposable = subscribe({ cont.resume(it) }, { cont.resumeWithException(it) })
        cont.invokeOnCancellation { disposable.dispose() }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just turn your Single into a suspend function:

```
suspend fun waitForRxJavaResult(): String? = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
        try {
            val result = resultSingle.blockingGet()
            cont.resume(result)
        } catch (e: Exception){
            cont.resume(null)
        }
    }
```

Comment: blockingGet() will block the current thread so suspendedCoroutine is useless in that case. Prefer using the callback APIs of RxJava.

Comment: I invite you to fix your code and I will upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:+'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:+'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-rx2:+'
```

And in code add:

```
fun <T> Maybe<T>.toDeferred(coroutineScope: CoroutineScope) = coroutineScope.async { awaitSingleOrNull() }

fun <T> Single<T>.toDeferred(coroutineScope: CoroutineScope) = coroutineScope.async { await() }
```

Usage:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
            val result = getItemMaybe().toDeferred(this).await()
            ...
        }



 fun getItemMaybe(): Maybe<Int> {
       
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this one :

```kotlin
suspend fun <T> Observable<out T>.toCoroutine(): T {
  return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    val subscription = this.subscribe(
      { continuation.resume(it) },
      { continuation.resumeWithException(it) }
    )
    continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
      subscription.unsubscribe()
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to convert the callback aspect to coroutines with `suspendCancellableCoroutine` block builder!